# Why am I getting Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.HostingEnvironment..ctor()' when using MVC from source?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I downloaded the source for MVC from https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc and in a ASP.NET 5 Starter Web project I added `global/global.json` at the solution level.

In `global.json` I pointed to where the MVC source is:

```
{
    "sources":  [ "C:\\development\\github\\Mvc\\src" ]
}
```

When I build and run the project I am getting:

[image]

Can anyone point out what I might be doing wrong? I would like to be able to run an ASP.NET project and debug MVC.

Answer (score 4):

Shooting blind here but this is the most common issue when it comes to using sources: make sure you are using the packages and the sources from the same feed/branch.

When you clone the sources from ASPNET's GitHub repos, for most repos the default branch is `dev`. The code in that branch, corresponds to the packages from MyGet (https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2) not NuGet.

However, if you use the packages from NuGet with the code in the `dev` branch (or vice versa), you will mostly sure hit strange errors (missing methods, incorrect parameters, etc) like you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

**LAST EDIT** Having a similar issue I found this source:

http://davidfowl.com/diagnosing-dependency-issues-with-asp-net-5/

The most important part of it is that **the version of the packages differ from the one of the dnx**. Still, packages are not able to specify the minimum dnx version they require, hence the issue. ASP.NET team says they're going to mark the minimum version of the dnx a package requires, so this error will disappear, however we'll have to live with it until then.

Here's a quotation which is related to your/mine issue from the article (no dynamics as I supposed earlier):

> If you ever see method missing of type missing exception or possibly an assembly load failure, chances are you ended up running betaX packages and betaY dnx or vice versa.

**MY SOLUTION (checked and it worked!)**

1. If I either use a **specific runtime version equals to the version of the packages**, or I just left the **Specific Runtime Version unchecked** then everything was just fine,
2. Also, if package versions are specified with asterisk, say, 1.0.0-*     instead of 1.0.0-beta6, there were lots of compile/intellisense       errors.

So, the bottom line is: all version must match exactly, at least for now.

Comment: @Hey you: The link is to an article by the guywho's answer has highest score. How ironic! 

MVC 6 is brand new (still a preview), so most of the articles are going to remain, or will improve so as to reflect the demand of information. Once the articles goes away, probably noone will be interested in this question.

Or blindly following the rules is more important?

Answer (score 0):

As the above answer explained this is the path that you should see in your project:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS":  "1.0.0-beta2",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta2",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta2",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Routing": "1.0.0-beta2",
    "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-beta2",
    "EntityFramework": "6.1.2"

}
```