# Can I debug into asp.net core source code?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How can I attach the MVC 6 source code or dlls into my project so that I could debug into it. I need to see the actual flow of few things.

Comment: This shows you how to debug ASP.NET Core source code:
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-debug-asp-net-core-source-code-448544c16473?sk=58f24ef1f6b39d0bd2927cd36dbd690c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Clone the repo(s) that you want for debugging from [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet)
2. Add a global.json file to your solution, similar to the one [here](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/master/global.json)
3. In the sources property, add the path(s) to the src folders that you got from github. For example:

   ```
   {
       "sources": [ "src", "D:\\dev\\aspnet\\mvc\\src" ]
   }
   ```
4. Run and the sources in `D:\dev\aspnet\mvc\src` should be used instead of the NuGet packages from NuGet/MyGet.

PS: Make sure you are using the sources and the packages from the correct branch. Otherwise you might hit strange issues like the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826853/why-am-i-getting-method-not-found-void-microsoft-aspnet-hosting-hostingenviron)

Comment: What's the proper way of building the downloaded source? I receive so many error no matter which repo i get. Are there any steps involved?

Comment: Can you give more details about the errors? The code should build without any additional steps. All you need is to have the latest KRE, assuming you got the code from the dev branch.

Comment: This is what I did to get me throughhttps://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/2966#issuecomment-245876542

Comment: how about new version of visual studio that does not have global.json?

Answer (score 3):

As of beta4, the sources node in global.json has been changed to projects.

```
{
    "projects": [ "src", "D:\\dev\\aspnet\\mvc\\src" ]
}
```